# Laravel Auth - If user is not logged in hide Controller regenerated Edit and Delete buttons [Yajra DataTables]

Tags: ajax, authentication, conditional-statements, laravel-7

I added Laravel Auth to my Yajra Laravel Datatables but for the life of me I cannot seem to figure out the  code for the controller so that **if a user is not logged in then hide Controller regenerated html buttons**

**Here is the AjaxdataController.php**:

```
class AjaxdataController extends Controller
{                

            //base page
            function index()
            {
                return view('student.ajaxdata');
            }

            //view data and make dynamic EDIT and DELETE Buttons per record 
            function getdata(Request $request)
            {
                $students = Student::select('id', 
                                            'first_name', 
                                            'last_name'                           
                                            );
                return Datatables::of($students)
                    ->addColumn('action', function($student){
                        //EDIT AND DELETE BUTTONS
                        return '<a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary edit" id="'.$student->id.'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit</a><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger delete" id="'.$student->id.'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Delete</a>';
                    })
                    ->make(true);
            }
}
```

**Here's what I am hoping to do with the AjaxdataController.php**:

```
class AjaxdataController extends Controller
{



    //base page
    function index()
    {
        return view('student.ajaxdata');
    }

    //view data and make dynamic EDIT and DELETE Buttons per record 
    function getdata(Request $request)
    {
        $students = Student::select('id', 
                                    'first_name', 
                                    'last_name'                                                                  
                                    );
        return Datatables::of($students)

        //if logged in then addColumn()
        if (Auth::user()){

            ->addColumn('action', function($student){
                //EDIT AND DELETE BUTTONS
                return '<a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary edit" id="'.$student->id.'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit</a><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger delete" id="'.$student->id.'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Delete</a>';
            })
        }
            ->make(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

**1) In the "use" section at the top of app\Http\Controllers\AjaxdataController.php, import the Auth Facades:**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

**2) Edit the addColumn() api like so:**

```
    ->addColumn('action', function($contact){

    if (Auth::user()) { 
    //IF LOGGED IN SHOW EDIT & DELETE BUTTONS
        return '<div class="btn-group"><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary edit" id="'.$contact->id.'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit</a>          <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger delete" id="'.$contact->id.'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Delete</a>
                </div>';

    }else{
    //IF LOGGED OUT SHOW THIS
        return '<p class="text-info font-weight-bold">Login to Edit or Delete</p>';

    }

})
```